# How to work with a ZipArchive in C#

Tags: c#, c#-ziparchive

I have a ZipArchive and am looking to access a file inside. I am not sure how I would do this, but I have a list

```
List<ZipContents> importList = new List<ZipContents>();
```

Which has two parameters:

1. `ZipArchive` which is called `ZipFile`
2. `String` which is called `FileName`

Inside the `ZipArchive` which is `importList.ZipFile` I need to find an XML file that has the same name as the Zip file name.

Currently I have this:

```
foreach (var import in importList)
{
    var fn = import.FileName; // This is the actual file name of the zip file 
    // that was added into the ZipArchive. 
    // I will need to access the specific XML file need in the Zip by associating with
    // fn

    // ToDo: Extract XML file needed 
    // ToDo: Begin to access its contents...

}
```

So for example the code is looking into the ZipArchive with the name `test.zip`. there will be a file called `test.xml` that I will then need to be able to access its contents.

Like I said above I need to be able to access the contents of that file. I am sorry I have no code to support how to do this, but I have not been able to find anything else...

I have looked through a lot of the ZIpArchive documentation (including: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and other posts on SO on how to do this, but I have come up empty. Would anyone have an idea on how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I was hoping that I would have at least been able to access it by filename using `import.ZipFile.Entries["test.xml"]`, but i was unable to even get far enough to target it...

Comment: Is it a single xml entry or can there be multiple xml entries?

Comment: if it's a single xml entry, simply take your archive name, and do a string.replace on it, replacing .zip with .xml, then extract as per normal...

Comment: using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
 using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(docloc)) {
  zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256; //if archive is encrypted.
  zip.Password = somePassword;
  //if this is a passworded archive..
  ZipEntry entry = zip(docloc.Replace(".zip",".xml");
  entry.Extract(ms);
 }
 b = ms.ToArray;
}

I plugged that into a code converter, so it might need some slight tweaking, but it appears correct from the best of what I can tell.  Sorry about the formatting, doesn't work so well in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the archive to a directory (may as well use temp since I assume you don't want to keep these):

```
archive.ExtractToDirectory("path string");

//Get the directory info for the directory you just extracted to
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("path string");

//find the xml file you want
FileInfo fi = di.GetFiles(string.Format("{0}.xml", archiveName)).FirstOrDefault();

//if the file was found, do your thing
if(fi != null)
{
    //Do your file stuff here.
}

//delete the extracted directory
di.Delete();
```

Edit: To do the same thing just unpacking the file you care about:

```
//find your file
ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive
                         .Entries
                         .FirstOrDefault(e => 
                             e.Name == string.Format("{0}.xml", archiveName));

if(entry != null)
{
   //unpack your file
   entry.ExtractToFile("path to extract to");

   //do your file stuff here
}

//delete file if you want
```

Comment: Thanks for posting! In `archive.ExtractToDirectory("path string");` what exactly is `archive`. Would that be my `import.ZipFile`?

Comment: that would be your ZipArchive object

Comment: If you don't feel like unpacking the whole thing, you can actually unpack individual files as well, but it is a little bit more involved.

Comment: Everything seems to be in order except the `di.Delete();` I keep getting an error there saying The directory is not empty. Is there a way to delete the directory anyway?

Comment: use `di.Delete(true);` instead

Comment: Yup found that. Any chance in knowing how to extract the files to memory instead of the temp dir?

Comment: you could use entry.Open() which returns a stream of the file

Comment: What about all of the files though?

Comment: You would have to loop through each ZipArchiveEntry and open a stream to that one file.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help!

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN you linked does a rather good job explaining how to access the files.  Here it is applied to your example.

```
// iterate over the list items
foreach (var import in importList)
{
    var fn = import.FileName;

    // iterate over the actual archives
    foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in import.ZipFile.Entries)
    {
        // only grab files that end in .xml
        if (entry.FullName.EndsWith(".xml", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            // this extracts the file
            entry.ExtractToFile(Path.Combine(@"C:\extract", entry.FullName));

            // this opens the file as a stream
            using(var stream = new StreamReader(entry.Open())){
                // this opens file as xml stream
                using(var xml = XmlReader.Create(stream){
                    // do some xml access on an arbitrary node
                    xml.MoveToContent();
                    xml.ReadToDescendant("my-node");
                    var item = xml.ReadElementContentAsString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will extract a single `xml` file called `file.xml` and read it to an [`XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) object:

```
var xmlEntry = importList.SelectMany(y => y.Entries)
                         .FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Name.Equals("file.xml",
                                                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
if (xmlEntry == null)
{
    return;
}

// Open a stream to the underlying ZipArchiveEntry
using (XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(xmlEntry.Open()))
{
    // Do stuff with XML
}
```